# external javascript/HTML not working...very basic basic/beginner

Tags: javascript, html

HTML FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p id="hi">HI</p>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="onClick1()" value ="CLICK ME">

<script src="myfunc.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Script

```
<script>
function onClick1(){
    document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML = "hello";
}

</script>
```

Google chrome saying LocalException:ReferenceError: onClick1 is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

.js and html file is saved on desktop in same folder...

Comment: Have disabled adblock aswell...but still the exception occurs

Comment: Remove the script tag in myfunc.js file.

Comment: Yup,now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the script tag in `myfunc.js` file and write as follows. This is because a page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function onClick1(){
        document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML = "hello";
    }
});
```

You need to include the script tag only if you include the script (here its `onClick1()` function) inside the HTML file itself as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p id="hi">HI</p>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="onClick1()" value ="CLICK ME">

<script>
function onClick1(){
    document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML = "hello";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that the `$(document).ready` function is part of the [tag:jQuery] library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `myfunc.js` in same folder, you don't have to write `{}`.

```
function onClick1(){
     document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML = "hello";
}
```